# It is possible to do an if within eloquent queries without having to do the whole LARAVEL query

Tags: laravel

I am trying to do a query in eloquent but apparently I will have to use normal SQL queries as I want to avoid having to do 2 times the same query but in the second one adding the where.

```
$seller = Lead::selectRaw('count(leads.id) as total, concat(users.name," ",users.last_name) as fullName')
                        ->join('users','users.id','leads.user_id')
                        ->where('status_id',$status)
                        if ($project != null) {
                            ->where('project_id',$project);
                        }
                        ->whereRaw('ticket_id is not null')
                        ->groupBy('fullName')
                        ->orderBy('fullName','ASC')
                        ->get();
```

In this query I have the problem when I integrate the IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the if statement between chained methods:
You can solve that this way:

```
$sellerQuery = Lead::selectRaw('count(leads.id) as total, concat(users.name," ",users.last_name) as fullName')
                        ->join('users','users.id','leads.user_id')
                        ->where('status_id',$status)
                        
                        ->whereRaw('ticket_id is not null')
                        ->groupBy('fullName')
                        ->orderBy('fullName','ASC');
if ($project != null) {
                            $sellerQuery->where('project_id',$project);
                        }
$seller = $sellerQuery->get();
```

Comment: Aaaa so that's how it should be used, thank you very much :D